# mysql join 2 table to select one row fields with multiple rows

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join

I need to join two table as follows - table 2 'value' on table 1 'price_1', 'price_2' & 'price_3' so I can output price label instead of the price value. Not sure how approach this in codeigniter. Do I use join the then nested select?:

**table 1**

```
id  |   price_1   |   price_2  |  price_3
1   |     6       |      5     |     4
```

**Table 2**

```
 id | label | value
1   |  £6.50 | 6
2   |  £2.50 | 5
3   |  £4.00 | 4
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: `label` doesn't really have '£' sign in it, does it? And consider normalizing your data - table1 (id, price_id, price)

Comment: `label` does have '£' in it as it's text and is only used to display price. The price "code" is the value in `price_1`, `price_2` and `price_3` and these are the ones I need to join with `value` in table 2. These are existing tables I am using for another purpose, so prefer not to change them, there is another id associated with the table 1 row , but I have not included it here for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

You can first make a select from table 1. Then:-

```
$tags = array();
foreach($record_from_table1 as $record)
{
   $tags[] = $record['price1'];
   $tags[] = $record['price2']; 
   $tags[] = $record['price3'];
}
```

Then make array_unique($tags)

Make select query from table 2 and get corresponding label values and echo them.

Comment: He wants to join on `price_1`, `price_2` and `price_3`, not on `id`.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for pointers, but did it this way, based on [Codeigniter Join with Multiple Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15992236/codeigniter-join-with-multiple-conditions?rq=1)

```
$this->db->select('p1.label as pa_1, p2.label as pa_2, p3.label as pa_3, p4.label as pa_4, p5.label as pa_5');
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->join('table2 as p1', 'p1.value = price_1', 'left');
$this->db->join('table2 as p2', 'p2.value = price_2', 'left');
$this->db->join('table2 as p3', 'p3.value = price_3', 'left');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Thanks, Dan