# CI MySQL query join tables and where statement does not return all row

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I have 3 tables that I want to join, however when I use where statement on the third table, and the third table doesn't have it, it does not return the row from the first and second table even though I'm using left join.

```
Table 1
+---------+--------------+----------+
| acc_PID | acc_name     | acc_type |
+---------+--------------+----------+
|       1 | Account 1    |    1     |
|       2 | Account 2    |    1     |
|       3 | Account 3    |    2     |
|       4 | Account 4    |    1     |
+---------+--------------+----------+

Table 2
+-------------+-----------------+-----------+
| journal_PID | journal_account | trans_PID |
+-------------+-----------------+-----------+
|      1      |        1        |     1     |
|      2      |        2        |     2     |
|      3      |        1        |     3     |
+-------------+-----------------+-----------+

Table 3
+-----------+----------------+
| trans_PID | trans_location |
+-----------+----------------+
|     1     |       1        |
|     2     |       1        |
|     3     |       2        |
+-----------+----------------+

// CI query
$this->db->join('table_2 b', 'a.acc_PID = b.journal_account', 'LEFT');
$this->db->join('table_3 c', 'b.trans_PID = c.trans_PID', 'LEFT');
$this->db->where('a.acc_type', '1');
$this->db->where('c.trans_location', '1');
$this->db->group_by('a.acc_PID');
$query = $this->db->get('table_1 a');
$result = $query->result();
```

Now from the data above, if I use ($this->db->where('c.trans_location', '1')), the result won't return Account 4 as there is no data of acc_PID ='4' in table_2 and table_3, however I want the result to return Account 4 too even though there is no data of account 4 in table 2 and table 3, without $this->db->where('c.trans_location', '1'), the result shows account 4 too, however with the where location statement it does not return the row from table 1 even though I used left join, shouldn't it return result from table 1 too ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to add condition in join instead on where clause.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15992236/codeigniter-join-with-multiple-conditions

Comment: @AmiteshKumar stupid me! Thank you sir, please write your answer so I can accept it as an answer.

Comment: @AmiteshKumar wait, that still does not show the account that has no data in the table 2 and table 3 if I used, 'LEFT', but if I don't use 'LEFT', it returns all trans in all location, while I only need trans_location ='1';

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add condition in Join instead on where clause.
If you write condition in where clause ,
it will add condition after the join means filter after filter,

OR do not use Left join and add where condition at last.

One more thing i did not found any  relation of table 1 with tanle 2 or table 3.If `journal_account`  is relation with table 1 then it should work.

I try it my self this is the solution i think :

```
SELECT * FROM `table1`

INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.journal_account = table1.acc_PID

INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.trans_PID = table2.trans_PID

WHERE table1.acc_type = 1  AND table3.trans_location = 1 GROUP BY table1.acc_PID
```

**AND This Also :**

```
SELECT * FROM `table1`

INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.journal_account = table1.acc_PID

INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.trans_PID = table2.trans_PID AND table3.trans_location = 1

WHERE table1.acc_type = 1  GROUP BY table1.acc_PID
```

This will give me two Accoun  Account1 and Account 2

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The relation is from table_2.journal_account to table_1.acc_PID, so I have added the AND to be $this->db->join(table_3 c', 'b,trans_PID = c.trans_PID AND c.trans_location=1'); IF I don't use left join, it does not return account 4 which does not have relation in table 2 and 3, IF I use left, it return account 4, but also result from table 3 that trans.location other than '1'.

Comment: @Charas I added the query in my answer hope it will help you if yes please accept the answer.

Comment: Yes thank you, turns out your code works perfectly fine, what makes my result returns all data in table_3 is because I used SELECT(SUM(CASE WHEN table_3 bla blac and forgot to add CASE WHEN AND transaction_location=1). Anyway thanks a lot for your help.